# Notification.permission is set to denied and not present in blocked

Tags: push-notification, web-notifications

On my localhost in chrome during unit testing of Notification permission, I have closed the browser native notification permission box by clicking on (x)

[image]

after that I am not able to change / remove it to default from browser Setting > Content Settings > Notifications

**localhost** is not visible in blocked list, but when I check on console in chrome **Notification.permission** value is set to "denied"

Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to close and reopen the browser.

You can find the permission in the browser settings only if you click "Block" or "Allow". If you click "X" you deny permission only temporary.

In any case you can also [check / change the preferences](http://blog.pushpad.xyz/2017/08/reset-browser-permission-for-web-push-notifications/) for a website by clicking on the lock icon near the address bar.